# Kotlin & Spring in Docker Container | Could not find Main Class com.project.mainapplication

Tags: spring, docker, kotlin

I am trying to run Kotlin & Spring in docker container. But the in gradle file specified main application could not be found.

```
participy-api-1  | Error: Could not find or load main class com.project.mainapplication
participy-api-1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.mainapplication
```

My Gradle file.

```
FROM gradle:latest AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle clean build

FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

I have similar configuration with pure java project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The official spring documentation helped me a lot, but I have still some open issues.

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

RUN microdnf install findutils

COPY . /workspace/app
RUN ./gradlew clean build
RUN mkdir -p build/target/dependency && (cd build/target/dependency; jar -xf ../../libs/Participy-0.0.1.jar)

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib/* /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF/* /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes/* /app/classes
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.root.participy.participy.ParticipyApplication"]
```

Due to official Docker-Spring documentation, it is recommended to use eclipse-temurin jdk. OpenJDK is deprecated.

https://www.docker.com/blog/9-tips-for-containerizing-your-spring-boot-code/

Problem is still, that `Error: Main method not found in class com.root.participy.participy.ParticipyApplication, please define the main method as:` on `docker-compose up -d`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your own answer you can use a multistage Dockerfile. However, your file has one problem as you have also mentioned and it is because you are building a Kotlin project. When main class is a Kotlin file you should do some change to the entypoint.

You should rename the class name and add "Kt" to it for this issue:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

RUN microdnf install findutils

COPY . /workspace/app
RUN ./gradlew clean build
RUN mkdir -p build/target/dependency && (cd build/target/dependency; jar -xf ../../libs/Participy-0.0.1.jar)

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib/* /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF/* /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes/* /app/classes
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.root.participy.participy.ParticipyApplicationKt"]
```